# Tree traversal explanation is required

Tags: java

What is the purpose of empty return, step by step explanation is needed, when    `printInorder(node.right)` is executed and node become null then where control will be transferred.

```
 void printInorder(Node node)
        {   
            if (node == null)
                return;

            printInorder(node.left);


            System.out.print(node.key + " ");


            printInorder(node.right);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend to think of recursive methods at a higher level of abstraction. That way, they should be easier to understand.

The question here is "what are the steps to print a node". If you look at the method's implementation, the answer is pretty clear:

> If the node is not null, print the left of the node, then the value of the node itself followed by a space, then the right of the node, otherwise print nothing.

If you were to describe *every* single step in printing a node, that would take a lot more words, but as you can see, this simple definition makes sense, is straightforward, and totally works.

The reason we need the `return` there is that when the `node` we are printing is non-existent, the only intuitive thing to do is to not do anything with it, isn't it? Practically speaking, this also provides and end to the recursion and avoids an NPE when you try to access `left` of a `null` node.

Answer (score 0):

If for the current `node`, `node.left` or `node.right` are `null`, calling `printInorder(node.left)` or `printInorder(node.right)` respectively should simply return without printing anything. Hence the `if (node == null) return;` statement.

As an alternative, you can simply avoid making the recursive call in such cases:

```
void printInorder(Node node)
{   
    if (node.left != null) {
        printInorder(node.left);
    }
    System.out.print(node.key + " ");
    if (node.right != null) {
        printInorder(node.right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy for such a simple solution!!.